# Help! Sharepoint main page gone after unextend

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I unextended my sharepoint site and now I can not access it. 404 not found.

Unextended with https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc287717%28v=office.12%29.aspx instructions

[image: This image: the drop down to delete the main sharepoint is empty. Sharepoint is not even detecting it exists]

IIS on server still shows site and sharepoint still has all the links and even the /sites under the lists but nothing will redirect. localhost on the server wont even route to the sharepoint page.

Please and thanks for your help!

I also tried this but did not work: http://shrinispeaks.blogspot.com/2011/05/sharepoint-unextend-web-application.html

Comment: Did you only have one iis site that you unextended?

Comment: Okay so I got it pseudo working. I extended the main site to a mirror settings version of itself. It shows up twice in IIS on the server but it does function and held all of it's settings.

If someone can direct me on the proper way to unextend and revert the settings back to just the main page I would appreciate it. Thank you and have a great day.

Comment: Sorry user19952, just now seeing your post. Yeah I had Site: main, and Site:admin console, I was trying to make an external site and sharepoint kept glitching up when I made it anonymous. So I tried extending the main site and everything got jacked up.